# ConTeXt: Set up external figure for particular image type

Tags: graphics, floats, context, scaling

## Background

A document has a mix of SVG and PNG images.

## Problem

Changing the parameters for `\setupexternalfigure` affects both SVG and PNG images.

## Code

Consider the following code:

```
\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
  location={local,default,global},
  directory={images},
  maxwidth=\textwidth,
  maxheight=0.4\textheight
]
```

I'd like to change the `maxheight` option for PNG images, such as:

```
\setupexternalfigure[
  method=png,
  maxwidth=\textwidth,
  maxheight=\textheight,
]
```

However, this affects SVG images as well.

## Question

How do you apply different external figure setups based on image type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mailing-list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/106223.html):

```tex
\setupexternalfigures[
  location={local,global,default},
  width=\textwidth
]
\defineexternalfigure[svg][width=1cm]
\defineexternalfigure[jpg][width=2cm]
\defineexternalfigure[png][width=4cm]

% Won't be applied because there's no process action.
% Default (\textwidth) is used, as defined above.
\defineexternalfigure[pdf][width=6cm]

\starttexdefinition includegraphics #1
  \splitfilename{#1}

  \processaction[\splitofftype][
    jpg=>{\externalfigure[#1][jpg]},
    png=>{\externalfigure[#1][png]},
    svg=>{\externalfigure[#1][svg][conversion=mp]},
    default=>{\externalfigure[#1]},
    unknown=>{\externalfigure[#1]}
  ]
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext
  \includegraphics{kitten.jpg}
  \includegraphics{mill.png}
  \includegraphics{cow.pdf}
  \includegraphics{tiger.svg}
\stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 2):

We can define a new external figure type files using `\defineexternalfigure`, then override the `\externalfigure` to use the new figure type when selected file is a `png` file.

```tex
% Requires LMTX/MkXL!
\setupexternalfigure[
    width=1em,
    height=1em,
    order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
    location={local,default,global},
]

\defineexternalfigure[png][
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\textheight,
]

\unprotect

\let\old_externalfigure=\externalfigure

\tolerant\def\externalfigure[#1]#,[#2]#,[#3]{%
    \doifelseinstring{.png}{#1}{%
        \old_externalfigure[#1][png][#2]%
    }{%
        \doifelsefileexists{#1.png}{%
            \old_externalfigure[#1.png][png][#2]%
        }{%
            \old_externalfigure[#1][#2][#3]%
        }%
    }%
}
\protect

\starttext
    \externalfigure[cow]
    \externalfigure[cow.pdf]
    \externalfigure[mill]
    \externalfigure[mill.png]
    \externalfigure[mill.png][width=5em]
    \externalfigure[cow][png][width=5em]
\stoptext
```

If you ask on the ConTeXt mailing list, someone else probably has a much cleaner way of doing this.